# DDD external entity reference

Tags: web-services, model, architecture, entity, domain-driven-design

I have an aggregateRoot named **Project**.

This project can have a sub-entity named **GitRepository**. This Entity represents access to a external git repository (like Github, Bitbucket).

Here's an example of how should look my persisted data (I use NoSql DB):

```
Project {
  id: String
  name: String
  GitRepository: GitRepository {
    externalRepoId: String // e.g. reference to the external github repo ID
    externalToken: String
}
```

The **GitRepository** Entity contain properties that allow me to retrieve more data from such external service (for instance repository name or collaborators).

The thing I don't understand when I have external reference is how the aggregate root should be stored (I guess I should store the external ID references of Github). But then how I can create my complete AR that fill the data (collaborators, repository name, ...).

Here's an example of how my Aggregate root should look once data are fetched from external service.

```
Project {
  id: String
  name: String
  gitRepository {
    externalRepoId: String
    externalToken: String
    repoName: String
    collaborators: List []
    repoCreatedAt: Date
    ...
  }
}
```

#### In that case I would have a modelisation in my DB that is different from my Domain model. Is it valid?

PS: An other option is to duplicate the data and store every informations I can get from Github, but in that case I can have inconsistencies (if the user update its data on external service)

Comment: take a look on this thread, maybe it can help you: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/307101/is-the-use-of-nosql-databases-impractical-for-large-datasets-where-you-need-to-s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would really consider whether the external repository is a different aggregate root than the internal one.  I know it seems ideologically simpler to say they are the same thing, but they clearly are not.  The idea of a "Complete AR" for your project shouldn't include things that can be changed outside of your application.  Create a separate AR for your external repo and I think most of your problems will go away.

Comment: But in my case the external repository is an entity not an AR.

Comment: I'm saying that you are likely wrong, that it is not an entity, it is a separate AR.  You have an AR (Project), which has an entity (ExternalRepo), which contains attributes (externalRepoId, externalToken, externalRepoType?)  You also have an AR (ExternalRepository) which contains all the bits from the external repository that you don't have control over, including collaborators, etc.  This way you draw a boundry around the things that you don't retrieve with a single database call.  And you don't load up each repo when you are just getting a list of projects.

Comment: This is how you allow your models to be significantly different from your database structure.  You really have two disparate databases here that you are trying to merge into one AR, the NoSQL DB, and the remote repository (GitHub, BitBucket, etc)..  This is likely a mistake, as they are separate "things", both in your data representation, and in "real life".  A remote repository is not a "part" of the project, it's something the project links to.  The linkage is "part" of the project, and so goes into its AR.